# Opening a Window in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been told that opening/showing a window should be done using Window services otherwise It's considered as a violation of MVVM.

I found this after searching

```
    class WindowService : IWindowService
    {
        public void ShowWindow(object viewModel)
        {
            var win = new Window();
            win.Content = viewModel;
            win.Show();
        }
    }
```

but IWindowService has the following error:

> Cannot access internal interface 'IWindowService' here.

So assuming that this is the right method to open a new window, how to proceed? If it's not, what's the best alternative?

Comment: You need to define your window opening interface. Your code is trying to [reference this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/IWindowService.cs,d9afa6e5c4384134,references) which is internal to WPF. Create an interface called IMuhWinderpOpener with a ShowWindow method and implement that.  Also, the VM should be assigned to the DataContext. Also, `new Window()` is pointless. Also, you shouldn't just copypaste code and run it. Understand what it's implying and apply that understanding to your application.

Comment: whatever reason you have in mind for opening a window from within a service, you definitely can work it out otherwise. after all it is pointless for a service to have a user interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the interface that your `WindowService` class implements somewhere:

```
public interface IWindowService
{
    void ShowWindow(object viewModel);
}
```